# Elixir: Test failure messages

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

Using Elixir's ExUnit for unit testing, everyone seems excited about the test failure messages. However, if I am testing anything other than `==`, I can't seem to get a useful error message.

For example

```
assert String.contains(my_string, "expected string")

    Expected truthy, got false
```

I prefer to write my tests so that my failures are more informative, allowing me to quickly iterate on the feedback they give. Is there a way to get a more informative test failure? e.g.

```
Expected "an unexpected string" to contain "expected string"
```

Comment: You could write an `assert_contains` macro which does this or pass a custom message to `assert` which it'll print on failure, but I'm not sure what kind of solution exactly you're looking for.

Comment: All asset does is check truthiness. You can supply a message, but on its own, it won't introspect what you're running that produces the result under assertion. This has come up before, e.g., https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/elixir-lang-core/KYAkagiKr0w, but that's still not automatic like you're asking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the particular case of testing against `String.contains?`, you could consider the regex match operator `=~`, as it will report a better test failure message out of the box.

Generally though, ExUnit's `assert` won't know about the inner semantics of every function in the standard library. This is why you can provide a custom error message:

```
assert String.contains?(my_string, "expected string"),
       ~s(Expected #{inspect my_string} to contain "expected string")
```

If you have many asserts for `String.contains?/2`, you can define your own assertion:

```
def assert_contains(string, substring) do
  assert String.contains?(string, substring),
         "Expected #{inspect string} to contain #{inspect substring}"
end

test "my string" do
  assert_contains my_string, "expected string"
end
```

Here are the expressions `assert` and `refute` will recognise and tailor the output for in Elixir 1.3:

- `=` match operator
- `match?/2` function
- `!` negation
- `==` equality operator
- `<` less than
- `>` greater than
- `<=` less than or equal
- `>=` greater than or equal
- `===` strict equality (distinguishes floats and integers)
- `=~` regular expression match operator
- `!==` strict inequality
- `!=` inequality
- `in` membership in enumerable

Most of these get the same special treatment: they are infix operators, and `assert` will report on the `lhs`, `rhs` values it sees.